# Can I get rid of the Signing section? (Sandbox vs. Hardened Runtime)

Tags: xcode, sign, osx-gatekeeper

I have two apps which are quite similar. One is working "as I want it" while the other doesn't. So I try to get them matched somehow. Basically one stumbles over the GateKeeper hurdle. Now that one has a section in the XCode settings

[image]

which does not appear in the working variant.

[image]

Since GateKeeper is linked to signing my first try would be to get rid of that "Signing" section. Is that somehow possible?

---

Actually the app with issues is trying to access the calendar. But it's not listed in the system's settings under security. So you can't grant access. (This is really a Vista moment. I'm just poking around in a mist I can't see through. I'll probably start asking different later...)

---

P.S. Also I found out that the working app seems to benefit from some nostalgia-setting. It has a

[image]

while the not working shows

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found out how to control that. In the Entitlements file you have to add a record

[image]

Once that is added the App Sandbox shows rather than the Hardened Runtime.

---

P.S. Hmm. I wasn't looking carefully. Sandbox shows, but Hardened Runtime still is sticky. And when building the app it's actually no change. So this is only half an answer...

---

P.P.S. Well, getting rid of the Hardened Runtime was too simple. There is a little [image]right to the tab which removes the section. Anyhow, this still did not resolve my issue and I opened  [another question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61274744/security-settings-dialog-does-not-list-my-app)