# Security settings dialog does not list my app

Tags: xcode, security, macos-catalina

My app requires to access the calendar. Up to Catalina that worked with the sandbox with no big issues. Now under Catalina the app does not show in the security settings:

[image]

I have set the Hardened Runtime with calendar access (also tried Sandbox with no different effects):

[image]

Since I believe this is related to that signing stuff, here's my setting:

[image]

Strangely enough I have another app which had been developed in parallel also using the calendar. And that app *is* listed in the security setting.

So likely I'm missing something. But what?

Comment: I found a solution: I stopped developing for MacOS. Too simple...

Answer (score -1):

Try: reboot the Mac, try your app again. Sometimes, weird problems resolve by themselves after a reboot.

Edited: This is not meant to be a bad joke, or to insult the skill and capability of the person asking the question, but when I read:

> Strangely enough I have another app which had been developed in parallel also using the calendar. And that app is listed in the security setting.

I assume the other app has a very similar or identical set-up and signing config, etc., otherwise the person asking the question would have tried changing something to make them similar or identical.

So it sounds like the kind of situation that doesn't make sense. I have a few (painful) memories when I rebooted my Mac and situations like that went away. I suspect that memory corruption, bugs in the OS, etc., can cause small failures as time goes on, and a fresh start can sometimes help.

Comment: Well, in former times a reboot was needed - almost never. Luckily Apple more and more gets into Windoze habbit: reboot. Since posting this question I definitely had to reboot more than once. Anyhow, just read my comment below the question.

Comment: I wouldn't mind if you commented "Did you try to reboot?". But as an anwer? No, that's not an aswer.